# Footer keeps disappearing once I add overflow: hidden to the body (using Bootstrap 4)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hey trying to achieve a no scroll for the body tag

I have used overflow: hidden on the body and it achieves the no scroll but it makes my footer disappear. Is there anyone that can help with this. I am using bootstrap 4 and I am using the SAME exact code from the bootstrap 4 website: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/ the only thing I have changed is that I have added a background picture which is the code below.

NOTE: I do want this to eventually work on mobile but I have looked it up and I might be facing some hurdles but I can use Javascript to achieve this later on. If you have a work around for that ISN'T Javascript. Please please feel free to share. Thanks

```
#cover {
    background: #222 url('img/umanoide-ooanFhSbn0g-unsplash.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    color: white;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center
}

#cover-caption {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: ALSO can provide any other additional code too!

Comment: Please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Let us know [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) and what didn't work.